# casting arrays returned by NSURL.getResourceValue in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, casting, tags, nsurl

I have spent all day trying to get useable results from **NSURL.getResourceValue** for **NSURLTagNamesKey** in swift.  The function should take the path name as a string and return an array of strings for the user tags.  I have a version of this that works in Objective C, but have not been able to re-write in Swift.

This is the current version of the code:

```
    func listTags(filePath:String)->[String]{
    //convert path string to NSURL
    let theURL : NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)!

    //get tags for NSURL -- should be NSArray of NSStrings hiding in an AnyObject?
    var tags : AnyObject?
    var anyError: NSError?
    tags = theURL.getResourceValue(&tags, forKey:NSURLTagNamesKey, error: &anyError)

    //unwrap tags object? This part never works
    let tagArray = tags! as [AnyObject]

    //insert every item in tag array into results array as a String
    var results = [String]()
    for object in tagArray{
        results.append(object as String)
    }

    return results
}
```

The code will compile but breaks when it tries to convert the AnyObject to any other type.  I have tried every combination  I can think of -- [AnyObject], [String], NSArray, with/without exclamation points and question marks.

Am on verge of giving up on Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself...

The method `getResourceValue:forKey:error` returns a value - a `Bool`, indicating whether the container you passed in as the first argument has been populated. Unfortunately you're assigning the value of this boolean to `tags` - your container! - which means that whatever was passed in to this container by Cocoa is immediately over-written. This worked for me...

```
var tags : AnyObject?
var anyError: NSError?
var success = theURL.getResourceValue(&tags, 
                       forKey:NSURLTagNamesKey, 
                       error: &anyError)
if success {
    println("container contents \(tags as [String])") // -> [AutoLayout, Swift]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 2, getResourceValue(:forKey:) returns `() throws`, i.e., void type which throws errors, so the answer above will no longer work.  It needs to be wrapped in a do {try} catch{} construction without the anyError variable:

```
do {
    try theURL.getResourceValue(&tags, forKey: NSURLTagNamesKey)
    return tags as! [String]
} catch {
    // process the error here
}
```